# Getting extra software in every live boot session?

Tags: boot, software-installation, live-usb

Almost all releases of Ubuntu comes with a pre-installed Mozilla Firefox.
If we live boot from USB with Ubuntu, we will find Firefox at our use, but if we installed some other browser, for example Chromium, Google Chrome,or Opera, we will find them missing in the next live boot session, for obvious reasons.

Is there some way that I can keep an extra (not pre-provided/pre-installed) software (like those extra browsers) in the USB, so I will find them in every live boot session henceforth?

I would like to clear it up that, I don't wish to install Ubuntu in the USB, just want to find an extra software in live boot session.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a **persistent** live Ubuntu system. Such a system is basically a live system, but with the addition, that there is a file named `casper-rw` or better partition labeled `casper-rw`, where the system stores program packages that you install and personal files that you save.

You can use **mkusb** to create a persistent live system of Ubuntu in a USB stick (or an SSD or even in a hard disk drive if you wish). It helps if it is a fast USB stick with at least 16 GB (but it is possible in smaller sticks too).

[help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)

[help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent)

[help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Notes_about_speed](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Notes_about_speed)

Comment: Now I've one more question!

I want to use Chromium, so if I allocate 2GB persistent space for Chromium and Mozilla Firefox Updates, will they both stay there in every live-boot session?

Besides, the cookies, the history, the temporary web data, will it also stay there?

Comment: Yes, all those program versions and data will be stored. It works with 2 GB for that purpose, but if possible, allocate more than 2 GB. It is a good idea to use a fast USB 3 stick with 16 GB or more total drive space.